# r.stats output parameter error

Tags: raster, grass-gis, qgis-3

The "r.stats" tool gives "ERROR: r.stats: Sorry,  is not a valid parameter" error and it creates empty file.

[image]

Comment: Please edit and add the QGIS version (ideally also the GRASS GIS version) you are using, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I checked on QGIS 3.6, to me the r.stats definition in QGIS processing looks broken:

```
r.stats separator="space" null_value="*" nsteps=255 sort="asc" -1 html=- > "/home/mneteler/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/processing/outputs/report.html" --overwrite
```

Here "html=-" should probably be "output=-" or it is some Processing magic (which doesn't appear to work).

See:

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/algs/grass7/description/r.stats.txt

I guess it should be reported as a bug to https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis/issues/